# Какой принцип работы сжатия LZ4:HC?

Tags: алгоритм, delphi

Столкнулся с проблемой реализации компрессии и декомпрессии с использованием алгоритма LZ4:HC на Delphi XE 10.2.3

Кто знает принцип работы данного алгоритма? Также интересует код основных функций (можно на asme)

Обычный (не HC) алгоритм меня не интересует.

Comment: Желательно без использования сторонних dll

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Меня интересует все, что может помочь мне в реализации данного алгоритма.
Желательно, конечно, чтобы мне дали последовательность действий для его реализации

Comment: Вот реализация на C: https://github.com/lz4/lz4

Comment: Спасибо - только документации там ноль целых ноль десятых

Comment: Вот реализация на Delphi https://github.com/atelierw/LZ4Delphi

Comment: Но они работуют не шибко стабильно